# Getting String value on jTree Java using Netbeans IDE

Tags: java, netbeans, click, jtree

I`m having a homework to create multi room selection for hotel.
My idea is by using jTree so I can select more more than one child of jTree. When we use jTree we can select more than 1 option by using ctrl+click. I started by creating project in Netbeans then added jTree from pallete. After that, I use custom code for TreeModel and add element like this :

```
public void generateRoom() {
    DefaultMutableTreeNode room = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Room");
    DefaultMutableTreeNode common = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Common");
    DefaultMutableTreeNode vip = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("VIP");
    DefaultMutableTreeNode vvip = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("VVIP");

    room.add(common);
    room.add(vip);
    room.add(vvip);
    DefaultTreeModel model = new DefaultTreeModel(room);
    jTree1.setModel(model);
}
```

After called the method in construcor, I added event MouseClick on jTree. The problem is I couldn`t find how to get multiple child from ctrl+click.

Thank you, hope somebody help me out..

I tried to add MouseOnclick like this :

```
private void jTree1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if (evt.getClickCount() == 1) {
        System.out.println(jTree1.getSelectionModel().toString());
    }
}
```

Yes, it worked with following result on console :
If I click only one child its result was :
    javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel 15980197 [ [Room, Common]@1 ]

If I use ctrl+click, it showed :
   javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel 15980197 [ [Room, Common]@1 [Room, VIP]@2 ]

The problem now is how do I get the string like Common or VIP..
Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use

```
public TreePath[] getSelectionPaths()
```

or

```
public int[] getSelectionRows()
```